# Changing Azure Databricks Workspace Settings via API

Tags: azure, rest, databricks, azure-databricks

I would like to control the Workspace Settings in the Admin Console of Azure Databricks via API(REST)

How should I do this or does anyone have the list of keys which correspond to each setting?

Workspace Settings in Admin Console-Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most of these options (*but not all!*) are configured via `workspace_conf` API ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/workspaceconf/setstatus)) that could be called directly, or used, for example, via [corresponding Terraform resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/workspace_conf):

```
resource "databricks_workspace_conf" "this" {
  custom_config = {
    "enableTokensConfig": false
  }
}
```

Unfortunately most of these settings aren't documented officially. There are few listed in the [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/workspace_conf#example-usage) and in the source code of some tools, like, [security analysis tool](https://github.com/databricks-industry-solutions/security-analysis-tool/blob/main/src/securityanalysistoolproject/clientpkgs/ws_settings_client.py#L14).

Comment: How about "permission settings" for token config? Can this be switched via API?

Comment: It should be done via permissions API. You can use terraform databricks provider as api reference ;-)

Comment: Thanks, found it [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/permissions#token-usage).

Comment: I maintain an unofficial list here which I'm due to update in the coming days https://github.com/fusionet24/DailyDatabricks/blob/main/tips/workspace-conf.md

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there is a [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/workspaceconf/setstatus) to achieve this. Sadly databricks don't publically document it. You can ask the solution architects for your account and they'll usually get you an answer.

That isn't always enough though. I maintain a list [here](https://github.com/fusionet24/DailyDatabricks/blob/main/tips/workspace-conf.md) that I try to update every so often.

If you want to find these properties yourself though, here is a quick guide...

1. Open up your Admin Console for your workspace on databricks
2. Press F12 to open Developer Tools
3. Goto the Networking Tab and Make sure you're recording traffic
4. Toggle the setting you wish to enable and inspect the traffic
5. Once you find the Request called workspace-conf you can inspect the payload to get your settings
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

To configure workspace settings you can use the Workspace Conf (Enable/disable features) endpoint of Databricks APIs (more information on the API reference [here](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/workspaceconf/setstatus)).

This is the endpoint:

```
/api/2.0/workspace-conf
```

Basically you have to create a PATCH request specifying the properies you want tyo set in the body:

```
{
    "property1": "string",
    "property2": "string"
}
```

Unfortunately I was not able to find the name of supported properties in the documentation, so I ended up using fiddler to intercept the requests form the Databricks workspace GUI to get the property name I needed.

If this can help, in my specific case I needed to configure the following property:

[image]

and it turned out that the property name to use in the PATCH request is `enableLibraryAndInitScriptOnSharedCluster`

Comment: I maintain an unofficial list here which I'm due to update in the coming days https://github.com/fusionet24/DailyDatabricks/blob/main/tips/workspace-conf.md